# How can I solve this error usging routerLink in angular 17.2

Tags: html, angular, routerlink

I'm trying to create an small app but in this moment I'm having this error with the routerLink by console. PD I'm new to angular

✘ [ERROR] NG8002: Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'.

and this is the html code:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/gastos', expense.id, 'Edit']">
    <i class="ri-edit-box-line"></i>
</a>
```

What do you think is my mistake?

The only configuration files I can modify are:
app.config.ts
app.routes.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using standalone components then just import *RouterLink* and it should work.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ CommonModule, RouterLink ],
  template: `
<a [routerLink]="['/gastos', expense.id, 'Edit']">
    <i class="ri-edit-box-line"></i>
</a>
`
})
export class MyComponentComponent { }
```

Answer (score 3):

please make sure you have
`@angular/router": "^17.3.0` in your package.json file
and import `RouterModule` in app.module
if you have `appRoutingModule` then import it in `imports: [appRoutingModule]`